# how to prompt the user to input the number between 1 to 20

Tags: c#, methods, tryparse

how to prompt the user to input the number between 1 to 20. If the user enters a string instead of a number, then it should display an error stating it's invalid and a valid number should be entered in c#.
This is throwing an exception when the user inputs a string input instead of a number.

```
    private static int number_of_participants()
    {          
        int tmp;
        int num;

        Console.WriteLine("enter no of students");
        num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (num < 1 || num > 20)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("this is not number. enter valid num");
            num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        else if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out tmp))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter no of students between 1 t0 20: ");
            tmp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        }

        Console.WriteLine("Invalid: enter number of students");
        num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        return num;
    }
```

Comment: See how you are using `int.TryParse`? You should use that _everywhere_ instead of `Convert.ToInt32`.

Comment: Doing this, it would throw an error that "cannot implicitly convert type bool to int"

Comment: If you cannot comfirm that the input string is a valid number, youcan try this method.[int.TryParse(string s, out int result)](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__). It reutrns true and give you the number on result if the input string is a valid numer, or it returns false.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
int num = Int32.Parse(Console.readLine());
```

or

```
int num = 0
Int32.TryParse(Console.readLine(), out x);
```

Int32.TryParse returns a bool so you can check if the user entered a number or not and then make your check if its within the range.

and you can find more about Int.TryParse in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private static int number_of_participants()
        {
            int num;
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("enter no of students");
                string input = Console.ReadLine();

                if (int.TryParse(input, out num))
                {
                    if (num >= 1 && num <= 20)
                        return num;
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("Number must be between 1-20.");
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("this is not number. enter valid num");
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

EDIT: I'll add some explanations.

First read the input always as string since you don't know if the user will type an integer or not then basically put this string to [int.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1) method. What this method do is it tries to convert your input to a valid integer if it returns true that means your input is a valid integer and you can continue. What I've done is if this method returns false I typed "this is not a number" because I know this can't be a number if TryParse method returns true then I simply check if the number is between 1-20 if not I type my message. If the input is number and if it's between 1-20 I return the number from the method named "number_of_participants"

Comment: You're welcome, please accept my answer if you find your solution for your question.